# Event subscribed using reflection not firing

Tags: c#, .net, events, reflection

I have this code:

```
var listProperty = typeof(WebserviceUtil).GetProperty("List" + typeof(T).Name);
var mainList = (ObservableCollection<T>)listProperty.
    GetValue(WebserviceUtil.Instance, null);
mainList.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(
    AllItems_CollectionChanged);
```

However, `AllItems_CollectionChanged` method never gets called.

Can anybody can tell me why?

---

**EDIT**

I have several Lists, e.g.:

```
public ObservableCollection<Banana> ListBanana { get; private set; }
public ObservableCollection<Book> ListBook { get; private set; }
// ...
public ObservableCollection<Officer> ListOfficer { get; private set; }
```

and I *really* want to avoid having to (un)subscribe manually to their `CollectionChanged` event, and there may be several listeners as well.

Comment: It seems like there must be a simpler, more testable way to approach this problem...

Comment: is your "list" property private?

Comment: I can get those properties, change their values, add/remove, but the event won't fire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's something missing from your question. The following complete program demonstrates that the CollectionChanged event is called.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ScratchConsole
{
    static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test<int>();
        }

        private static void Test<T>()
        {
            var listProperty = typeof(WebserviceUtil).GetProperty("List" + typeof(T).Name);
            var mainList = (ObservableCollection<T>)listProperty.GetValue(WebserviceUtil.Instance, null);
            mainList.CollectionChanged += AllItems_CollectionChanged;
            mainList.Add(default(T));
        }

        private static void AllItems_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("AllItems_CollectionChanged was called!");
        }

        private class WebserviceUtil
        {
            public static readonly WebserviceUtil Instance = new WebserviceUtil();
            private WebserviceUtil() { ListInt32 = new ObservableCollection<int>(); }
            public ObservableCollection<int> ListInt32 { get; private set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Woa! That was fast! I'll test it and I'll be happy to mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: There's nothing for you to test here. I'm just demonstrating that your question is incomplete. What are your expectations of when `AllItems_CollectionChanged` will be called? As demonstrated above, calls such as `Add` will raise that event. It wouldn't, however, be raised when the property itself changes. That is, if you set your `ListBanana` property to a whole new collection, the event wouldn't fire.

Comment: That's it, I cannot believe I have overlooked such a trivial thing. Thank you!